# Being notified when a post is currently being edited?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Provide indicator that another user is editing a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73924/provide-indicator-that-another-user-is-editing-a-post)
>   [Would a “this edit is being improved” notification be useful?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90958/would-a-this-edit-is-being-improved-notification-be-useful)

Have you ever, after being editing a post for a while, realized someone else had already edited it, and lost all your work? I know that most of the time this isn't an issue, since the system will keep the most throughout edit. However, what happens if the edits are similar? Shouldn't people be notified when a post is currently being edited, so they don't waste their time editing it themselves?

My question, or proposal, is to have a way of letting people know whether or not a post is being edited *before* they waste their time.

Comment: Although perhaps not strictly a duplicate, waffles' answer explains why the feature is probably more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: @YannisRizos: I agree with waffles; however, I still believe that a slightly different solution might be viable. For example, the users could see hints of what the others are editing (like a preliminary version of the post as partially edited by someone else). Or maybe the post edits could be seen by everyone in real-time.