# Show when a post is in the process of being edited

Tags: feature-request, edits

My issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35700969/3536236 On this answer I dig in a comment and stated that the poster should add more than just a bare-bones code answer, then we got into a little chat about Impatience and editing, as should be exampled by the link.

What this brings up to me is it would be very, **very** helpful to have a small note on a post that when I load a question (and answers) on a page that I can see a flag marker that the Q or A is *currently being edited*.

Who by and the details of the edit are not needed, simply the fact that someone has the question open as an edit and that I can wait a few minutes to see the additions before posting my comments or scoring based on the pre-edit condition of the post.

This is **not the same** as [Would a "this edit is being improved" notification be useful?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90958/would-a-this-edit-is-being-improved-notification-be-useful) where the answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109768/307529 is a good answer, but the answers core reasoning only applys if the information is given in the context of a parallel edit.

All the topics on META that I've found about this seem to be based on parallel edits and on people editing posts at the same time needing to know if someone else is, I think that bare if at all croses over to this where I think a comment or a vote on a question/answer can be better saved/posted if they knew that the question/anwser was currently being edited.

> This is **not** a duplicate post of [Provide indicator that another user is editing a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73924/provide-indicator-that-another-user-is-editing-a-post) 
>   That post is all about parallel editing this is about informing readers that a post is being edited. There is a crucial difference here.